# Checking Language type of data coming from database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, spell-checking

I have stored data in SQLite database  in both English and Hindi.

I have two columns in database, `name` and `address` respectively, and I am storing some raw in English and some in Hindi statically.

Now, My Question is **"How can I know about that which type of data I am fetching from database ?"**

Is it in English language or Hindi language?
Is there any language checker available in Android?

How can I get done this task ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You can use an array with all the letters from the alphabet (upper and lower case) and check if the first letter of your data is inside or not.

Comment: Is your data static or dynamic?

Comment: @PiyushGupta I am storing data in SQLite Manager statically. To store in Hindi, I am using google translator.

Comment: If you'r data are static then you can use Locale for that which support multiple language.

Comment: @Virthuss Little confused about your suggestion, will you please explain it in little more ?

Comment: if you are fetching the data from the database then directly fetch the Hindi or English as per your need with the appropriate query

Comment: @PiyushGupta I have already used Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage() to check the device language setting. But, Same way How can I do for data coming from the database ?

Comment: @JaiminModi Everytime you have a data containing letters, if you want to know if it's english or hindi, you can see if the data contains at least one of the element in a list containing the letter of the latin alphabet in upper and lower case

Comment: You need to create two different `values` folder. One for English and one for Hindi. Both folders contains the same string defination.

Comment: @Virthuss  Ok, I think that your way will be working. Thanks trying it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create a new column for flag 'language_type'

When value equals

- 1 :- Hindi
- 2 :- English

While entering the data, You can check the flag accordingly.